# Navigation bar not opening when page is resized

Tags: html, css

I have this problem that my navigation bar does not open when I click on it (when the page is resized). I use Bootstrap, first I load jQuery and next Bootstrap.

```html
<head>
  <title>How to be a Front-End Developer</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toogle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-main">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/w3newbie.png"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-main">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a class="active" href="#">Strona główna</a></li>
          <li><a href="#aboutWhat">O czym jest ta strona?</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kursy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#don">Donacja</a></li>
          <li><a href="#footer">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: You've made a typo - `data-toogle="collapse"` should be `data-toggle="collapse"`

Comment: Yes Shiny, you are right... I dont believe. That is really bad, im need to rest